# Vert.x request handler and blocking db queries

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, vert.x

How can i translate this piece of code correctly in vert.x?

normally, in spring or in a simple sevlet with a template engine to output an html response i'll do like this

```
function test(request, response) {
  templatecontext tc = getContext();

  init conditions

  if (condition1) {
    retrieve data from db ({
      asyncresult -> {
        tc.put("data1", data1)
      })
  } else if (condition2) {
    other code

    if (condition 2.1) {        
      retrieve data from db ({
        asyncresult -> {
          tc.put("data2", data2)
        })
    }
  }

  get other data from db and put in context
  template.eval("templatefile", tc)
  write to response
}
```

the problem is, retrieving data from database is an handler of asyncresult, so i cannot grant that template evaluation is made with data1 or data2, because retrieving of async without falling in a callback hell.

I've not really understood rxjava2, but i feel i'm trying to kill a bean with a spoon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [futures](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Future.html) and [composition](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_sequential_composition). See the `ComposeExample` in [`vertx-examples`](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/future/ComposeExample.java) repo:

```
public class ComposeExample extends AbstractVerticle {    

  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {
    Future<String> future = anAsyncAction();
    future.compose(this::anotherAsyncAction)
      .setHandler(ar -> {
        if (ar.failed()) {
          System.out.println("Something bad happened");
          ar.cause().printStackTrace();
        } else {
          System.out.println("Result: " + ar.result());
        }
      });
  }

  private Future<String> anAsyncAction() {
    Future<String> future = Future.future();
    // mimic something that take times
    vertx.setTimer(100, l -> future.complete("world"));
    return future;
  }

  private Future<String> anotherAsyncAction(String name) {
    Future<String> future = Future.future();
    // mimic something that take times
    vertx.setTimer(100, l -> future.complete("hello " + name));
    return future;
  }
}
```